# Is it possible to change the image in the default theme 'Twenty Eleven'?

Tags: theme-twenty-eleven

Is it possible to change the image in the default theme 'Twenty Eleven'?

If yes, how is this done?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just replace the default header image, under images/headers/path.jpg in your theme folder.

Comment: Thanks. Is it ok, to replace it with an image that is less deep? Or would doing this make things 'off'?

Comment: if you have an image of  a smaller size, three things can happen. 1. You get empty air on the right side, 2. the image is centered or 3. image is streched to fit width - all depending on css. Best is to use an image of same size, or change the CSS.

Answer (score 0):

Go to Appearance > Manage Themes > Header. There you can upload your own image file. If its size differs from the default size you can crop the image in the next screen.